# Laravel Pagination not working if query contain HAVING statement

Tags: pagination, eloquent, laravel-5.6, having, having-clause

**Laravel** Pagination query issue with **having clause**, please see the query below

```php
$data = DB::table('jobs as j')
    ->selectRaw('j.*, (case
        when (seeker_action = 'like' and employer_action = 'like') then 'match'
        when (seeker_action is null and employer_action = 'like') then 'employer-liking'
        when (seeker_action = 'like' and employer_action = 'delete') then 'rejected'
        else seeker_action end) as 'action'')
    ->join('profiles_jobs as p', 'p.job_id', '=', 'j.id')
    ->where('p.profile_id', '=', 2)
    ->whereRaw('(p.seeker_action is not null) or (p.seeker_action is null and p.employer_action = 'like')
        and j.deleted_at is null')
    ->having('action', 'employer-liking');

$data = $data->paginate(10);
```

Error I am received is below:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'action' in 'having clause'
>   (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from jobs as j inner join
>   profiles_jobs as p on p.job_id = j.id where p.profile_id = 2 and
>   (p.seeker_action is not null) or (p.seeker_action is null and
>   p.employer_action = 'like')\nand j.deleted_at is null having action =
>   employer-liking)

I posted this on github discussion and got a way around method but I want to know if there is any better solution for this.
[Github laravel having issue discussion](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3105#issuecomment-409288024)

Comment: please post the error

Comment: Hi Seva, I have edited my question above please check.

Comment: Why do you detect all the different actions when you only want to get `employer-liking`? Can't you just use `->where('seeker_action', null)->where('employer_action', 'like')`?

Comment: @jonas doing this to get the pagination using filter with other different action along with employer-liking

Comment: I don't understand your reply. Do you want to select other actions or not? Your query detects all actions and then discards all but `employer-liking`.

Comment: @jonas  i have to select other actions because i want to filter with all actions not specific to employer-liking. For example i want all jobs where action = match or action=employer-liking or action=rejected. So having clause will be dynamic in this query

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use [conditional `WHERE` clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#conditional-clauses):

```php
$data = DB::table('jobs as j')
    ->select('j.*')
    ->join('profiles_jobs as p', 'p.job_id', '=', 'j.id')
    ->where('p.profile_id', '=', 2)
    ->whereRaw("(p.seeker_action is not null) or (p.seeker_action is null and p.employer_action = 'like') and j.deleted_at is null")
    ->when($action === 'employer-liking', function($query) {
        $query->where('seeker_action', 'like')
            ->where('employer_action', 'like');
    })
    ->when($action === 'match', function($query) {
        $query->whereNull('seeker_action')
            ->where('employer_action', 'like');
    })
    ->when($action === 'rejected', function($query) {
        $query->where('seeker_action', 'like')
            ->where('employer_action', 'delete');
    });

$data = $data->paginate(10);
```

You should also replace `whereRaw()` with [`where()` and `orWhere()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping).

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?